# Lag when rendering many Picker items

Tags: react-native

There is a problem with speed of Picker component rendering after arrow-down icon is touched. User can feel a lag. The problem is present when there is lots of picker items. What could I do to enhance the user experience in this case? Could a portion of Picker items be rendered first somehow? React-native-picker-android is used here, maybe this is the case with this component but I'd like to know best practices to deal with this performance issue.

[image]

When arrow-down is touched this.state.modal is changed to true and Picker component reacts to this change so that it appears on the screen.

```
    {this.state.modal ? <View style={{height: 200, backgroundColor: '#E8E8E5'}}>
      <Picker
        pickerStyle={styles.picker}
        itemStyle={{color: '#F99704'}}
        selectedValue={this.props.value}
        onValueChange={this.props.onChange}>

        <Picker.Item label={'07:00'} value={'07:00'} />
        <Picker.Item label={'07:00'} value={'07:00'} />
        <Picker.Item label={'07:00'} value={'07:00'} />
        <Picker.Item label={'07:00'} value={'07:00'} /> 
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it appears as though you're building the picker when the this.state.modal is true. Why not build it regardless, then show/hide it based on state? You could even do some fancy animation. Just a thought. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: good hint, thanks, what would you suggest to handle it? manipulating height of View or overflow ?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd try height probably first